# Can I use ModelBinder to get object without adding parameter to action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, modelbinders

I am new in MVC. I have a view that contains many dropdowns and viewmodel with many lists. Most of these lists are static so I want to cache retrived records. I can do this with (custom) Model binders, but I dont like that to actually use (custom) Model Binder I need to add parameter for every object in Action method like this:

```
public ViewResult SubmitNewValue(MyViewModel viewMod, IEnumerable<List1> list1, IEnumerable<List2> list2, IEnumerable<List3> list3 ...)
{
viewMod._list1 = list1;
viewmod._list2 = list2;
viewMod._list3 = list3;
...
return View(viewMod);
}
```

What I think would look better is something like:

```
public ViewResult SubmitNewValue(MyViewModel viewMod)
{
viewMod._list1 = ModelBinders.GetInstanceFor<List1>();
viewmod._list2 = ModelBinders.GetInstanceFor<List2>();
viewMod._list3 = ModelBinders.GetInstanceFor<List3>();
//I am able to wrap above to separate function like PrepareViewModel(viewMod)
...
return View(viewMod);
}
```

Is there a function/way to do this?

I am also not sure if I chose good approach but my viewmodel is losing lists for dropdowns, so I need to somehow readd them to ViewModel after [HttpPost] for example.

Comment: Are the lists necessary for the view model or are they just used to populate drop downs?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. I think they are necessary for the viewmodel cause I need them to populate drop downs. I know that ViewData can be used instead but ViewModel seems to be better approach. Those lists are used only for dropdownlists.

Comment: If your collection properties of  `viewMod` are not binding  using just `MyViewModel viewMod` then its because you view is wrong. You should show it so that your errors can be corrected (look at the html your generating - you should have `name` attributes such as `name="_list1[0].someProperty"`, `name="_list1[1].someProperty"` etc)

Comment: My option tags don't have this attribute, only select tag has. I cannot find a way to set up dropdownlistfor so it will send also collection in POST action.
'@Html.DropDownListFor(it => Model.SomeProp, new SelectList(Model.MyIEnumerable, "Id", "Description", Model.SomeProp))' . Internet says that I should repopulate collection after every post action example: [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187648/why-my-model-in-post-lose-dropdownlist-items)

Comment: @Kostrzak. If those collections are for generating options in dropdownlists, then you dont generate form controls for them (that would be crazy). If you need the collections again because `ModelState` is invalid and you need to return the view, then you get the data again from your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modelbinder's sole job is to bind data from the request (querystring or post body) to *parameters on your action method*. So, no, if there's no parameter, the modelbinder does nothing with the data.

You *can* access the data directly from the request, i.e. `Request["list1"]`. However, that's the raw data as the modelbinder would receive it, before it actually did any of the work it does. In other words, you would need to manually do type-coercion or new up things, etc., with that data.

That said, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/163532). What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve, because there's probably a better way.

Comment: You've said that modelbinders bind data from the request, but if I create a custom Modal Binder implementing IModelBinder then I can pass (create?) the object which is not in the request (I can have a simple button on the form) and still the object will be created and passed as parameter. I think when I add a parameter to POST action method, the default model binder will try to find a matching request data and if it fail, it will try to use Custom Model Binders to create an object and pass it as parameter. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Custom modelbinders are a solution in search of a problem. There's perhaps a use-case for them, but I've yet to come across a single suggestion of using a custom model binder that couldn't be solved by just doing things correctly in the first place. Again, please detail exactly what you're trying to achieve, and then perhaps someone can tell you how to do that in a correct and maintainable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ControllerBase.ViewBag` Property to store resources for the view to use.

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    public ActionResult SubmitNewValue() {
        populateDropDownLists();

        MyViewModel model = GetDefaultViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SubmitNewValue(MyViewModel viewMod) {
        processMyViewModel(viewMod);
        populateDropDownLists();
        return View(viewMod);
    }

    void populateDropDownLists() {
        //These could be cached lists
        ViewBag.List1 = GetList1();
        ViewBag.List2 = GetList1();
        ViewBag.List3 = GetList1();
    }
}
```

And then in your view you can access the lists to populate your dropdowns

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyViewModelProperty, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.List1, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control select" })
```

The view model should not be responsible for storing the lists. Since the lists are only for populating the dropdowns in the view then they should be seperated out

Comment: I don't have a problem with passing data (lists) to the view. I can use viewbag, viewdata, viewmodel etc. In your solution I need to create and add a method to controller for every list I need. I am not saying that this is a bad practice, but if I can create custom ModelBinder which creates a list for me and which I can use in every controller, then it there should be a way to get those object explicit by sth like ModelBinder.GetObject<>() ...

Comment: Then what you are looking for has nothing to do with the model binder.

Comment: Then @ChrisPratt answered your question. You could possibly try using DI to get you lists.

Comment: You could even use a service locator and get the lists directly in the view if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Yeap, I think I've tried to use Model Binder in a different way than it is supposed to be used and will need to create own class which will store all needed lists. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain what is exactly wrong with adding lists to the viewmodel ? As far as I understand, viewmodel should contain all the data that View needs no matter if this data is needed for dropdownlist, textbox or just a label. Is there an easy way to distinct what kind of data should be stored in ViewModel and what in ViewBag/ViewData. Sorry for moving out of original question.